# SKPaymentQueue restoreCompletedTransactions restores same transaction multiple times

Tags: iphone, ios, storekit, in-app-purchase

I have an auto renewable subscription for 6 months setup up in my purchases via iTunes connect. I created a test user and bought that subscription, now when i try to restore my purchases, it returns the same transaction multiple times in the transactions array in

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
```

I use the following piece of code to restore my purchases.

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
```

Please advise what i am doing wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to call finishTransaction.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed [storekit](https://github.com/idzDeveloper/IDZStoreKit) for non consumable product. See if you can use it or you can suggest me any changes for the same. :)
Enjoy !